# Bootstrap Tooltip Not Displaying

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use bootstrap tooltips - but currently I cannot get them to display. I've followed all the instructions on the Bootstrap Docs guide, but they still aren't working. Is there something I might be missing?

HTML:

```
<button class="btn btn-white btn-sm" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Refresh inbox"><i class="fa fa-refresh"></i> Refresh</button>
<button class="btn btn-white btn-sm" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Mark as read"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i> </button>
<button class="btn btn-white btn-sm" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Mark as important"><i class="fa fa-exclamation"></i> </button>
<button class="btn btn-white btn-sm" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Move to trash"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i> </button>
```

JS:

```
 $(function () {
            $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
 })
```

<del>And a code pen can be found here:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LpzPxR</del>

My initial guess was that something was wrong with the CSS <del>but I can't seem to get it to work in the pen either</del>.

EDIT: I've fixed the issue in the codepen but the actual template is still displaying incorrectly - http://i62.tinypic.com/2ik2u6s.jpg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're almost there: you are just missing jquery, before `bootstrap.js`.

From bootstrap documentation:

> Some plugins and CSS components depend on other plugins. If you include plugins individually, make sure to check for these dependencies in the docs. Also note that all plugins depend on jQuery (this means jQuery must be included before the plugin files)

See ***[forked codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yYzBXW)***

NB: I also added `font-awesome.css` as you have icons from that latter library.

---

**Edit:** from [this screenshot](http://fr.tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2ik2u6s&s=8#.Vh2d7fntlBc) posted in comment and the conversation, it appeared that OP had also `jQuery UI Tooltip`, which is conflicting with bootstrap tooltips.

Comment: That works in the code pen but didn't fix the template - when hovering the template is displaying like this: http://i62.tinypic.com/2ik2u6s.jpg

Comment: Hm, in the above screenshot it appears that you toggled the *hover* state on the button, but that's not what triggers the tooltip. Might be a silly question, but did you also tried triggering a *mouseenter* event on this same button?

Comment: I did - but even when I don't toggle the hover and use the mouseenter on it's own it still displays the same

Comment: Try the following from the js console see if it helps: `jQuery('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()`

Comment: It gives me the HTML of the four buttons - but nothing else

Comment: Do you have a `data-original-title` attribute in the html output?

Comment: I don't no - however in the original template that works I do

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92200/discussion-between-michael-p-bazos-and-liane-stevenson).